# German equivalents of the French expression "pour un oui ou pour un non"

Tags: expression, french

> Tu ramènes toujours tes complexes ethniques, **pour un oui ou pour un non**, dans toutes les discussions, même les plus anodines.

- {literally}: *You always dredge up some complex about your ethnic origin, **be it for a yes or a no**, in virtually all discussions, even of the most harmless nature.*
- {more naturally}: *You always dredge up some complex about your ethnic origin **at the drop of a hat** in virtually all discussions, even of the most harmless nature.*

This hyperbolic expression is used to refer to someone's annoying tendency to insist on doing something with no apparent rhyme or reason, as if on a whim.

> Pleurer, c'est un truc de fille à ses yeux, comme si elles avaient le droit de pleurer **pour un oui ou pour un non**.

- *The way he sees it, crying is a girls' thing -- as if they had every right to shed tears **over any little thing**.*

How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in German?

Answer (score 2):

> *Bei jeder **un**passenden Gelegenheit* regst du dich auf.

*You make a fuss at any **un**matching opportunity.*

This is word-play on the everyday term *bei jeder passenden Gelegenheit*. As usual for German humor the **un** is planted in a deadpan fashion to give the Brits the missopportunity to complain about the missing humor.

---

A simpler way to express this idea is using **immer gleich** instead of *immer*:

> Du regst dich **immer gleich** auf.
>
> **Immer** regst du dich **gleich** auf.

Comment: "Bei jeder unpassenden Gelegenheit" Interesting, not something I could have come up with on my own. Is this phrasing commonly used and easily understood?

Comment: Yes, it's common. Also common: *Bei jeder passenden oder unpassenden Gelegenheit* ← you made a habit of it.